Cannot create a subscription via App Store Connect
I'm working on Testflight build of the app. I've removed the subscription I created previously to create it again, but this time I'm unable to create a subscription:

Checking the network console, I'm getting a strange issue I've never seen before.
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "id" : "a76b3891-f791-48a7-a7e9-3fec528c1202",
    "status" : "409",
    "code" : "ENTITY_ERROR.SUBSCRIPTION_CREATION_NOT_ALLOWED",
    "title" : "You cannot create new subscription.",
    "source" : {
      "pointer" : "/data/id"
    }
  } ]
}

I've tried re-inviting myself to the organization and waiting for a day. I also have full admin rights in the organization. Unfortunately, Apple Support doesn't respond and I'm on a tight deadline. Has anybody encountered anything similar? Subscription creation worked for me before

Looks like account holder must review and accept the Paid Applications Schedule (Schedule 2 to the Apple Developer Program License Agreement) in the Agreements, Tax, and Banking module in order to proceed

You should be able to access this agreement via the following link:
https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/agreements/#/

I also had the same problem for 2 days today.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Also facing the same issue. Any update. on this.
I had the Admin access and all the latest agreement has also accepted.


